# How can I combine vuepress dev mode with apidoc output?

Tags: vuepress

I want to add some docs to my project, there are two kind of docs, guide doc and apidoc, and I use apidocjs.com as my apidoc solution.

Vuepress has dev mode and build mode, I can make vuepress and apidoc work together in build mode, but I can not make it work in dev mode.

I have tried to output /api/ to .vuepress/api or .vuepress/public/api, they are all not work for me when I run vuepress dev docs. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself.

By this doc describing:
`https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/assets.html#public-files`

I just run apidoc and vuepress in this way:

```
mkdir -p docs/.vuepress/public/api && apidoc -i controller/ -o docs/.vuepress/public/api && vuepress dev docs
```